# dependent lookup doesn't work when the dependent inputField not displayed on layout

Tags: visualforce, lookup, filters, dependent-lookup

For `Case` object there are two input fields `Account` and `Contact`.

***I want the `Contact` `inputField` `lookup` to show only contact that belongs to `Account` `inputField` value chosen for this `Case`***

Referring salesforce documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters_defining.htm&type=0, I have setup `filter criteria` for `Contact` as below

`Contact: Account matches Case:Account` from suggested criteria.

The `Contact` lookup works perfect only if I have `Account` as `inputField` on the page. I want to set the Case `Account` from controller and don't want to show it on UI layout and be able to see case `Contact` lookup filtered by `Case` Account.

I tried below code for `Account` input for `Case`

```
<apex:inputField rendered="false"/>
<apex:inputHidden/>
```

But `dependent lookup filter for case contact based on case account` doesn't work unless I use below for `Account` input for `Case` edit layout

```
<apex:inputField/>
```

Is this a bug in salesforce?

Comment: The consideration page @https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters_notes.htm&type=0 for `dependent lookup` says `Versions 16.0 and higher of the Salesforce API support lookup filters. Lookup filters are enforced when you load data through the API.` NOW I am working with 17.0 and this is still the issue. Am I, greenhorn in salesforce development, making any mistake in understanding concepts here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work the dependent lookup properly both fields should be present in the page. One thing you can do, hide the Account lookup field by using style property `display:none;`. But as it is a lookup field there are a couple of other components present beside the input field. So wrap it inside a `<apex:outputPanel` and hide the panel instead as below.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="TestCaseController" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputPanel style="display:none;" >
            <apex:inputField value='{!myCase.AccountId}'/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:inputField value='{!myCase.ContactId}'/>
    </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This workaraound helps! Cheers!!!! Also please check my comments on original question.